# Losing quality, even if I save in a lossless format, once I save a screenshot

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, graphics-editing

As I take and try to save my screenshots, with any type of software, and any type of lossless format, I see a loss in color precision in the 4-bit range.

An rgb value of (20, 20, 20) crunches down unexplainably to full black, independent from the color mode used

I'm trying to pin point what could cause this very curious problem, and unfortunately without the possibility of saving normal screenshots I can't directly show you the differences in output from what I see before saving, and what I see after

Comment: Not really sure, but I'd be tempted to look at profiling, make sure WYSIWYG

Comment: 202020 in AdobeRGB will compress to 151515 sRGB, but I cant get lower than 131313 P3 whatever I try.

Comment: How do you know what the rgb value should be? And how are you taking the screenshots?

Comment: I'm just hovering it with Digital Colour Meter, saving a known quantity file at different output profiles. Whether saved as file or screenshot, I'm within 1 at all formats, so long as my colour profile matches. I know my screen is accurate, profiles were updated only Monday, with the full card.

Comment: Save as a BMP bitmap.  Do you still lose colors?

Comment: It's still within 1, if I view it as sRGB [as it's a profileless format, sRGB is a reasonable guess to make, I suppose. It's not a format I would ever use as it has no colour management capability so I don't know it well.] I can't even guess at what might be wrong without more info - What standard are you working to, when & how was your screen last calibrated, what's your input profile, is your colour workflow set up correctly in photoshop, is it going through any soft-proofing? What OS would also help.